# Desperately need help on $\epsilon$-$\delta$ limit question

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

Let $T$ be the function defined by letting $T(x)$ be the decimal expansion of $x$ truncated to five decimal places, where $x$ is some real number. So, for example:

- $T(1/2)=0.5$
- $T(π)=3.14159$
- $T(1/3)=0.33333$
- $T(1)=1$

Let $ϵ=10^{−5}$. Show that for every $δ>0$ there is some $x$ such that $|x−\frac{1}{2}|<δ$ and $|T(x)−\frac{1}{2}|≥ϵ$.

I've been given the hint that the numbers $0.4999…99$, with $n$ number of $9$s, are very close to $\frac{1}{2}$ for large values of $n$.

I don't know where to start, I've tried finding $δ$ the normal way with $\epsilon$ but there isn't a  clear function so I'm confused.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Apply the hint directly: for any $\delta$, take $x=0.4999...9$ where you have enough $9$s so that $|x-1/2|<\delta$. Then what is $T(x)$?

Comment: So if x=.49999 wouldn't T(x) be .49999 as well